# What is the most effective way to find distinct of columns in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a file of size 1TB. And we need to find the distinct values for 4 columns in the file.
So for example if we have columns A,B,C,D,E,F and so on. Among them we need to find all the distinct values in column A and create one file in HDFS. Similarly for B,C and D.

Note: We have to do this for only 4 Columns not for the remaining. There are total of 300 columns in the file.

We need to write Map Reduce for this. What would be an effective way to address this problem. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: is input to distinct B is output of filtering done in distinct value for A? OR all need to be done separately

Comment: There is no dependency between A,B,C,D and E. The output of one will not go to input of another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the mapper output a record for each column you need the unique values. So in your example the map will (with a single input record) output 4 records with the key being A,B,C,D.

In the reducer you can then handles all the values.

Depending on the details of what you need you may want to use a key that looks something like this: "A:value of column A"

Comment: I think this will work. But I have one follow up question, we have distinct records of A to be 1 million and distinct records of B to be 50 records, C to be again 50, D 100000m, E to 1 million.
So if we set number of reducers to be 5 and each key go to different reducers. Will this not be a bottleneck for 2 reducers. We might face stragglers right ?

Comment: No, If you have 10000 different values for D then these will result in 10000 different keys (the exact distincts you are looking for). These 10000 can be distributed over 10000 reducer tasks. The straggler effect depend on the maximum number of different values you have for a single distinct key. If you then still have such an effect you could consider using a combiner (partially reduce within the mapper task).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to filter out duplicate records, this can be done in few steps begin from mapper, combiner and reducer. Also you can use java Set. Mapper can output key= 
'Column A' Value='complete record'. Store keys in Set, if set contain key don't emit record. Same can be done in combiner. And may be you don't need reducer. Also need to workout so Set does not create out of memory error by clearing on some specific size.